# cursorUpdate called, but cursor not updated

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nscursor

I have been working on this for hours, have no idea what went wrong. I want a custom cursor for a button which is a subview of NSTextView, I add a tracking area and send the cursorUpdate message when mouse entered button.

The cursorUpdate method is indeed called every time the mouse entered the tracking area. But the cursor stays the IBeamCursor.

Any ideas?

Reference of the Apple Docs: [managing cursor-update event](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW1)

```
- (void)cursorUpdate:(NSEvent *)event {
    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void)myAddTrackingArea {
    [self myRemoveTrackingArea];

    NSTrackingAreaOptions trackingOptions = NSTrackingCursorUpdate | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
    _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect: [self bounds] options: trackingOptions owner: self userInfo: nil];
    [self addTrackingArea: _trackingArea];
}

- (void)myRemoveTrackingArea {
    if (_trackingArea)
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea: _trackingArea];
        _trackingArea = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class did you put this code in?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem.

The issue is, that `NSTextView` updates its cursor every time it receives a `mouseMoved:` event. The event is triggered by a self updating `NSTrackingArea` of the `NSTextView`, which always tracks the visible part of the `NSTextView` inside the `NSScrollView`. So there are maybe 2 solutions I can think of.

1. Override `updateTrackingAreas` remove the tracking area that is provided by Cocoa and make sure you always create a new one instead that excludes the button. (I would not do this!)
2. Override `mouseMoved:` and make sure it doesn't call super when the cursor is over the button.

   ```
   - (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
       NSPoint windowPt = [theEvent locationInWindow];
       NSPoint superViewPt = [[self superview]
             convertPoint: windowPt  fromView: nil];
       if ([self hitTest: superViewPt] == self) {
           [super mouseMoved:theEvent];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but using a simple `NSView` subclass that was a child of the window's `contentView` and did not reside within an `NScrollView`.

The documentation for the `cursorUpdate` flag of `NSTrackingArea` makes it sound like you only need to handle the mouse entering the tracking area rect. However, I had to manually check the mouse location as the `cursorUpdate(event:)` method is called both when the mouse enters the tracking area's rect **and** when it leaves the tracking rect. So if the `cursorUpdate(event:)` implementation only sets the cursor without checking whether it lies within the tracking area rect, it is set both when it enters **and leaves** the rect.

The documentation for `cursorUpdate(event:)` states:

> Override this method to set the cursor image. The default
> implementation uses cursor rectangles, if cursor rectangles are
> currently valid.  If they are not, it calls super to send the message
> up the responder chain.
>
> If the responder implements this method, but decides not to handle a
> particular event, **it should invoke the superclass implementation of
> this method**.

```
override func cursorUpdate(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Convert mouse location to the view coordinates
    let mouseLocation = convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

    // Check if the mouse location lies within the rect being tracked
    if trackingRect.contains(mouseLocation) {
        // Set the custom cursor
        NSCursor.openHand.set()
    } else {
        // Reset the cursor
        super.cursorUpdate(with: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this through a Google search, so I thought I'd post my solution.

1. Subclass the NSTextView/NSTextField.
2. Follow the steps in the docs [to create an NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html). Should look something like the following. Put this code in the subclass's init method (also add the `updateTrackingAreas` method):

   ```
   NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:(NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow) owner:self userInfo:nil];
   [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
   self.trackingArea = trackingArea;
   ```
3. Now you need to add the `mouseMoved:` method to the subclass:

   ```
   - (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
       NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
       if (NSPointInRect(point, self.popUpButton.frame)) {
           [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
       } else {
           [[NSCursor IBeamCursor] set];
       }
   }
   ```

Note: the `self.popUpButton` is the button that is a subview of the NSTextView/NSTextField.

That's it! Not too hard it ends up--just had to used `mouseMoved:` instead of `cursorUpdate:`. Took me a few hours to figure this out, hopefully someone can use it.

Comment: When you use the mouseMoved: method, you don't need the tracking area. Or to put it another way, NSTrackingArea is useless in NSTextView.