# Set correct cursor when a button overlays a scroll/text view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard, controls

My storyboard includes a scroll view (uneditable but selectable) that is overlaid with a second view containing a couple of buttons which are initially visible and eventually hidden. As I move the mouse over the scroll view, the text cursor displays as expected. But when the mouse moves over the buttons, the text cursor remains. I would have expected the cursor to change to an arrow.

What is the proper way to make the arrow cursor appear when over the buttons, when overlaying a scroll view? Can this be done within the storyboard or am I missing some code?

Thanks!

Comment: you are missing some code. oh yeah, please put here some code :)

Comment: At the moment, I have no specific cursor handling code, as I was expecting the default behavior of the storyboard hierarchy to display the arrow when the mouse is over a button and the text cursor when the mouse is over the scroll view, but not the buttons.

Comment: A scroll view can't be editable or selectable and doesn't change the cursor. What's in the scroll view, a `NSTextView`? Which view is focused (first responder)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cursorUpdate called, but cursor not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451872/cursorupdate-called-but-cursor-not-updated)

Comment: Correct, sorry about that, it's an NSTextView within the scroll view that is selectable. I've not explicitly set up a first responder for this window.